# Node.js on localhost

Tags: node.js

I am very new to node.js. I am developing a multiplayer card game. So, someone suggest me to use node.js with apache and php.

how?

Comment: It's not really an question, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You should narrow down, and ask a specific question. Also go to nodejs.org and at least watch the video to get know `node.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a bit research will solve your problem. It seems you have lack of information about sockets read and then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple chat server written in node.js. It should be a great starting point for multi-user communication in a web environment.

https://github.com/evert/nodejs-chat

Hope it helps!